# Codeigniter extended core class 'My_Model' not found on unix but OK in Windows?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, unix

Have setup a My_Model.php file in application/core/

Contents are:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Model extends CI_Model{

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function x(){

   }

}
```

This is then extended by one of my user Models - loginmodel.php :

```
<?php

class LoginModel extends My_Model{

   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   function checkAD() {

   }

}
```

All works Fine on my local Windows Bitnami WAMP development deployment but when deployed on the Unix/Apache host.....

**getting error:**

Fatal error: Class 'My_Model' not found in ..../application/models/loginmodel.php on line 2

httpd.conf issue maybe? Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Follow the file naming conventions. UNIX is case sensitive, while windows is not.

Comment: I think core/MY_Model.php should be also. And `class MY_Model extends CI_Model {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your application/config file prefix

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

try renaming as

> MY_Model

Answer (score 2):

Unix is case sensitive, not Windows. For example you should rename your file loginmodel.php in LoginModel.php, according to your code.

Comment: Did wonder about case sensitivity Windows v Unix but was focussed on the My_Model not the LoginModel - will check this.

Comment: According CI documentation, your class files should be named `ucfirst('class_name')` so in your case good practice would be `Loginmodel.php` and class itself too `Loginmodel`.

Answer (score 0):

You were all kind-of on the right track. Probably closest to the solution was @wolfgang1983. It was the name of the My_Model.php file. Changed it to MY_Model.php and boom. All the other naming issues seem to be irrelevant - thus far. Thanks